# MariaDB: Creating View from query with SET @variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I created a query where i set some variables at the start. Now i would like to create a view of this, but SET @ isn't allowed in mariaDB.

Here's the idea of the query (full query is very long and more of the same):

```
SET @Value1:=0;
SET @Value2:=0;
SET @ValueN:=0;

SELECT  id,Date,Name,number,Billing,
        IF(Billing='Value1' AND NOT isSpecial AND NOT isFirst
            AND performance.hour,@Value1:=@Value1+number,
        IF(Billing='Value2' AND NOT isSpecial AND NOT isFirst
            AND performance.hour,@Value2:=@Value2+number,
        ...
        IF(Billing='ValueN' AND NOT isSpecial AND NOT isFirst
            AND performance.hour,@ValueN:=@ValueN+number, '-'))) as Booking  
    FROM recording
    INNER JOIN performance
        ON performance.id=recording.performance_id
    WHERE customer_id='2'
```

I can "count" the columns with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Billing, customer_id, isProbatorik, isFirst`, but i can't find a solution to add the number to the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

If the `ROW_NUMBER()`is 1 and the number is 3, the next `ROW_NUMBER()`must be 4.

Is it possible to "count" each column by adding the number on each row?

Comment: Where are the closing parentheses?

Comment: The query is too big, so i just posted the idea of it. The query is working fine, but i can't find a way to put it in a view :(.

Comment: `SUM(Billing='Value1' AND NOT isSpecial AND NOT isFirst)` almost gives you the value without the @value1.

Comment: Thx, thats helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is an integer and you can use arithmetic at will. For example

```
 , 1 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(..) - 1) * 3  AS countx
```

to get countx = 1,4,7,..

Comment: I see, but i need to store the individual values, because ROW_NUMBER() doesn't know the value of the last row. If the first row is 5 (i can just use arithmetic) the second row will be 2 again, because ROW_NUMBER() doesn't know that i added value 4 to the first row. I have to count and add the individual value of the row to this count which has to be remembered by the next row.